# ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn

I am encountering the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py",
 line 87, in preload_check
     ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudnn_dll_name)   File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in
 __init__
     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin    ", line 1, in
 <module       File
 "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
 line 22, in <module    
     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File
 "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
 line 49, in <module    
     from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
 line 30, in <module    
     self_check.preload_check()   File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py",
 line 97, in preload_check
     % (build_info.cudnn_dll_name, build_info.cudnn_version_number)) ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'. TensorFlow requires that
 this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH%
 environment variable. Note that installing cuDNN is a separate step
 from installing CUDA, and this DLL is often found in a different
 directory from the CUDA DLLs. You may install the necessary DLL by
 downloading cuDNN 7 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn
```

I have installed the required "cuDNN 7" files in the directory mentioned in the %Path% environment, yet the statement

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

is not working. I have downloaded the cuDNN 7 files from the mentioned site:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn

I have gone through all the answers on StackOverflow and yet I am getting stuck with the same error. 
Please guide me on how to run the above statement.

Answer (score 2):

for me it was that i didn't install cuDNN.
download it according to ur cuda version and extract it in cuda directory

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did.

Step 1) Installed 'NVIDIA GEFORCE EXPERIENCE' in my computer to check my Driver version.

Step 2) The driver version was an old one. Update was available. So I updated my Graphic driver.

My GPU properties now are:-

```
NVIDIA GEFORCE EXPERIENCE Version 3.14.1.48
GeForce 940MX
Driver Version 398.82
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @2.50GHz
7.9 GB RAM
```

Now, through conda environment ( I created an environment named 'tensorflow' ), when I executed the statement

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Arnab Sinha>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

I encountered the following message :-

```
pandas 0.23.4 requires python-dateutil>=2.5.0, which is not installed.

pandas 0.23.4 requires pytz>=2011k, which is not installed.
```

I then installed the required packages by executing the following commands one after the other

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

and

```
pip install pytz
```

after which I ran the command in Python 3.6.6

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

which gave the output

```
1.10.0
```

Here is how I installed Tensorflow 1.10.0 into my computer. The Anaconda Navigator however does not have the update of Tensorflow 1.10.0. Please inform me if you have found the update for it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
Install missing CUDNN files as per the Tensorflow version listed here :

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows

Step 2 : `tf.test.gpu_device_name()` should output something like

```
/device:GPU:0
```

If you get error on Step 2 then you need to have the below :

- Tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0
- Python version(at least) 3.5-3.8
- MSVC 2019
- Bazel 3.1.0
- CUDNN v7.6
- CUDA 10.1