# ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll' , while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, python-3.6, cudnn

This is an issue that many of us must have come across. While installing tensorflow, this is one of the error messages that pops up for most of the users. I could not install Tensorflow 1.10.0 due to the following error that I posted a few days back at

> [ImportError: Could not find 'cudnn64_7.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824219/importerror-could-not-find-cudnn64-7-dll)

I am using Windows 10 and was trying to implement

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

through Conda environment.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.

Step 1) Installed 'NVIDIA GEFORCE EXPERIENCE' in my computer to check my Driver version.

Step 2) The driver version was an old one. Update was available. So I updated my Graphic driver.

My GPU properties now are:-

- NVIDIA GEFORCE EXPERIENCE Version 3.14.1.48
- GeForce 940MX
- Driver Version 398.82
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @2.50GHz
- 7.9 GB RAM

Now, through conda environment ( I created an environment named 'tensorflow' ), when I executed the statement

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\Arnab Sinha>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

I encountered the following message :-

```
pandas 0.23.4 requires python-dateutil>=2.5.0, which is not installed.
pandas 0.23.4 requires pytz>=2011k, which is not installed.
```

I then installed the required packages by executing the following commands one after the other

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

and

```
pip install pytz
```

after which I ran the command in Python 3.6.6

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and then

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

which gave the output

```
1.10.0
```

Here is how I installed Tensorflow 1.10.0 into my computer. The Anaconda Navigator however does not have the update of Tensorflow 1.10.0. Please inform me if you have found the update for it.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to the cuDNN Archive
2) Click on Download cuDNN v7.6.1 (June 24, 2019), for CUDA 10.0
 
       (you need CUDA 10 installed. NOT 10.1. If you installed the wrong version, uninstall 
        it and install the 10 which works with tensorflow-gpu)
3) Click on the link for your operating system.
4) Unzip it. It should unzip to a folder called CUDA. 
5) Go into the CUDA folder and copy the contents
6) Open the installed CUDA 10 location. For windows 10 it is "Download cuDNN v7.6.1 (June 24, 2019), for CUDA 10.0"
 
7) Paste the contents from your clipboard to the folder.
8) have a coffee. You are done!

Answer (score 2):

Jeremy Demers' answer worked for me, and I was able to repeat his process. However, I used cuDNN 10.1 instead of version 10 and installed `tensorflow version 2.4.0-dev20200705` first via `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, and then `pip install tensorflow-nightly to get the latest build.  Hardware: 2060 Super, 8GB.

#### Edit:

The recommended way to get tensorflow nightly via pip is:

```
pip install tf-nightly
```